# Closure in event handler

Tags: javascript, closures, eventhandler

```js
var element = document.getElementById('test-button');

//event handler
element.onclick = (function outer() {

  var counter = 0;

  return function inner() {

    counter++;
    alert('Number of clicks: ' + counter);
  };
})();
```

```html
<button id="test-button">Test</button>
```

I don't understand why the variable counter won't reset to `0` every time the button is clicked, or maybe when it's clicked, only the function `inner()` get executed, then why the variable counter get set to `0` when first click occurs.
The code is from this [link](https://app.pluralsight.com/guides/javascript-closures), after carefully read their explanation, I'm still confused.

Comment: Yes, your event handler is the inner function. outer function is only executed while setting the event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why the variable `counter` get set to 0 when first click occurs.

That is not the moment it gets set to 0. This happens when the assignment to `.onclick` happens. At that moment `outer` is defined *and* executed. So that is the moment `counter` is set to 0. No click is handled yet.

> only the function inner() get executed

Indeed. `outer` is only executed once, when the main script is executed on page load, and then never again. `inner` is the function that gets assigned to `onclick` and thus has the role of event handler. `inner` has access to the `counter` that is defined in `outer`, but `outer` is never executed again.

`outer` is a so-called immediately executing function.

As a comparison: you could achieve something similar with this code:

```
var counter = 0;
element.onclick = function inner() {
    counter++;
    alert('Number of clicks: ' + counter);
};
```

...but the downside now is that `counter` is a global variable, that could be altered by some other code. To make sure `counter` is *only* available to the click handler, a closure is created for it, which you could also do like this:

```
function outer() {
    var counter = 0;
    element.onclick = function inner() {
        counter++;
        alert('Number of clicks: ' + counter);
    };
}
outer();
```

The downside here is that `outer` has a so-called *side-effect*: it assigns to `element.onclick`. This is the reason to choose to *return* `inner` and leave it to the caller of `outer` to do something with it, e.g. assign it to `.onclick`.

Then we get something like this:

```
function outer() {
    var counter = 0;

    return function inner() {
        counter++;
        alert('Number of clicks: ' + counter);
    };
}

element.onclick = outer();
```

This is essentially the same as your code: the function is first defined, and then immediately executed. The function that gets assigned to `onclick` is the one that is returned by `outer`, i.e. `inner`.

Yet another way to achieve this encapsulation of `counter`:

```
function inner() {
    this.counter++;
    alert('Number of clicks: ' + this.counter);
}

element.onclick = inner.bind({ counter: 0 });
```

Here the we provide an unnamed object that is always passed as `this`-argument to `inner` whenever it is called. As we don't retain a reference to that object outside of this construct, we achieve the same principle: the counter's state is maintained, but is not accessible outside the handler.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear and thorough explanation! I understand now. When this `element.onclick = function inner()` part is inside the `outer()` function, I don't know what did you mean by " it assigns to `element.onclick`", may you tell me a little bit more?

Comment: So, `outer` is immediately executed: this you can see by the pair of parentheses `()` that follows right after its definition. It has a `return` statement and the value it returns is the `inner` function. So that means this who expression that executes `outer` will return `inner`, and that gets assigned to `element.onclick`.